# Running node.js script on dreamhost by cron or shell_exec()

Tags: php, node.js, cron, dreamhost

I'd like to run a node script on my shared server on Dreamhost once every x minutes. I've set up a cron job to execute:

```
cd /home/path && node app.js
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. I've also tried to put the same statement into a shell_exec command in php, but the script is still not (perhaps not completely) executed. When i'm manually running that command everything works fine.

The only thing I can think of is that the script needs about 15 seconds, which might be too long?

---

For anybody looking for this answer: running a nodejs app on dreamhost shared server seems to be restricted (for example [here](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-129095.html), but can also be found on dreamhosts support pages)

Comment: It could be a permissions issue or a syntax error in the cron job.  Can you show the crontab or at least the line(s) you added to it?

Answer (score 2):

script taking long shall not be an issue.

It would be nice if you digged into logs and found out what the error is, my bet - it will be self explanatory.

Meanwhile, I suspect the cause is in calling `node` **without** using full path. Cronjob scripts do not have `PATH` configured, as a result calling for `node` will very likely return `unknown command`. Solution would be: write in terminal `which node` to see full path and then use it instead.

As a result your cronjob script will look something like:

```
cd /home/path && /usr/local/bin/node app.js
```

Granted node is in `/usr/local/bin`

To view the errors in cronjob run command: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Thanks, but that's something I previously tried and (still) doesn't work. Where can I find the logs for cron? The general log dir seems to be empty.

Comment: what cronjob are you using? The supplied one with your distributor, is it not one of those fancy cronjobs built into cPanel or other control panel? What is your distributor? You got to give us some information on what you are using.